# Why request-scoped bean is not created from form values?

Tags: java, jsp, scope, request, javabeans

I've created such a JSP file:

```
<jsp:useBean id="ucz" class="pl.lekcja.beany.beany.Uczen" scope="request">
    <jsp:setProperty name="ucz" property="*"/> 
</jsp:useBean>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Podaj dane ucznia:</h1>

        <form method="POST" action="Ocen">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Imie:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="imie" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nazwisko:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nazwisko" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Punkty:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="punkty" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Oceń" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

With bean class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Uczen implements Serializable {
    private String imie, nazwisko;
    private int punkty;

    public Uczen() {

    }

    public Uczen(String imie, String nazwisko, int punkty) {
        this.imie = imie;
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
        this.punkty = punkty;
    }

    public String getImie() {
        return imie;
    }

    public void setImie(String imie) {
        this.imie = imie;
    }

    public String getNazwisko() {
        return nazwisko;
    }

    public void setNazwisko(String nazwisko) {
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
    }

    public int getPunkty() {
        return punkty;
    }

    public void setPunkty(int punkty) {
        this.punkty = punkty;
    }
}
```

And Servlet:

```
public class Ocen extends HttpServlet {

    private static final int PROG_PUNKTOWY = 50;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Uczen uczen = (Uczen)request.getAttribute("ucz");
        System.out.println(uczen); // <---- here prints null, always, there's no "uczen" object in attributes
        String czyZdal = "nie ";

        if (uczen.getPunkty() >= PROG_PUNKTOWY) {
            czyZdal = " ";
        }

        request.setAttribute("czyZdal", czyZdal);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/wynik.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And as I wrote in servlet's code, there's a point which always prints null, instead of created bean class. Bean is not created or it's not added to attributes.

processRequest() is called by both doGet() and doPost()

What's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You post your request to your `Ocen` servlet. When the servlet is executed, the JSP has not bee executed yet, so the `jsp:useBean` hasn't been executed yet, so the bean is not in the request yet.

`jsp:useBean` shouldn't be used anymore. The request parameters should be read in your controller servlet, and not in your JSP. You should use an MVC framework like Spring MVC or Stripes, that would automatically transform the request parameters into a form bean and pass this form bean to an action.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the problem, I see that there's two different request, dispatched by two different things, but i thought that there will be some kind of co-operation between those elements. I'm into Spring Framework, but for my own need I had to go back and do it on servlet/jsp level only.